# mongoDB ~ combining $exists / $nin?

Tags: mongodb

My mongo collection `foo` has a selection of documents, some of which with an array called `music`, some of these contain a value "`Blues`".

If I want to show all records where the array exists and they don't contain the word `Blues`, why does this not work (it appears to ignore first criteria)?

```
db.foo.find({
    music: { $exists: true },
    music: { $nin: ["Blues"] }
})
```

and yet this does:

```
db.foo.find({ 
    music: { 
        $exists: true,
        $nin: ["Blues"]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
> var obj = {music: 1, music: 2};
> obj
Object {music: 2}
```

It's also similar to

```
> var obj = {};
> obj.music = 1;
> obj.music = 2;
```

and then expecting that `obj.music` is somehow both `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't try , but you need to add $and to your query.Otherwise it will only apply the last statement.

```
db.foo.find ($and:[{music : {$exists : true}}, {music : {$nin : ["Blues"]}}}])
```

Comment: Good idea, but it should be `db.foo.find({$and: [{music : {$exists : true}}, {music : {$nin : ["Blues"]}}]})` :)

Comment: Yeah, I haven't try the code, just want to point out that the problem is that he's missing an "$and"

Answer (score 1):

Because of structure rules in programming languages. The syntax:

```
db.foo.find({
    music: { $exists: true },
    music: { $nin: ["Blues"] }
})
```

The best way to think about this (though it depends on driver and language here) is:

```
create an object with "music: { $exists: true }" and then add "music: { $nin: ["Blues"] }" to it
```

The latter overwrites the earlier